# navigate from one webBrowser to another webBrowser on the same form in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have one webBrowser named as webBrowser3 which is showing links to its content of an HTML File. Example :- One WebBrowser(webBrowser3) shows Table Of Contents(TOC) and i want on whichever chapter or its part i click, it shows its content on another webBrowser(webBrowser2) which is placed in same Form of webBrowser3. I have made Table Of contents(TOC) but when  click on any chapter, it shows its content on the same webBrowser(webBrowser3) in which TOC is placed.
I have tried it in the following way but it is not showing desired result.

```
  string toc = File.ReadAllText(StaticClass.ZipFilePath + "\\OEBPS\\IDSBooktoc.html");

         webBrowser3.DocumentText =toc;
```

I am not getting exactly what should i do in order to do it...
Here is my HTML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Table of Contents</title>
    <!--Styles for the Table of Contents-->
    <style>h1 {text-align: center}
    p {text-align: left}
    p.level_0 {text-indent: 0em }
    p.level_1 {text-indent: 1em }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="tocHead">Table of Contents</h1>
    <p class="level_0" height="2em">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen0">2008-21-0043 Chapter 1 Development</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen1">INTRODUCTION 1</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen2">TRADITIONAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen3">DEVELOPMENT BENCHES</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen4">ECU SYSTEM AND IT&amp;amp;V TESTING</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen5">INTRODUCTION TO THE ECU VIRTUAL PROTOTYPING [] []</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen6">VIRTUAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen7">CREATION OF THE VIRTUAL TEST ENVIRONMENT</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen8">USER INTERFACE</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen9">PLANT MODEL</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen10">SIMULATION PLATFORM</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen11">CONNECTING THE VERIFICATION TEST BENCH TO THE VIRTUAL ECU</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen12">COMPARISON: TRADITIONAL TEST BENCH VS VIRTUAL TEST BENCH</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen13">Case Study One: Transmission Management System</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen14">Discrete Outputs</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen15">Discrete Inputs</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen16">BENEFITS TO DATE</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen17">FUTURE INVESTIGATION AND IMPROVEMENTS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen18">CONCLUSIONS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen19">ACKNOWLEDGMENTS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen20">2008-21-0043 Chapter 2 Development</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen21">INTRODUCTION 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen22">TRADITIONAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen23">DEVELOPMENT BENCHES</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen24">ECU SYSTEM AND IT&amp;amp;V TESTING</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen25">INTRODUCTION TO THE ECU VIRTUAL PROTOTYPING 3</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen26">VIRTUAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS 1</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen27">CREATION OF THE VIRTUAL TEST ENVIRONMENT 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen28">USER INTERFACE</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen29">PLANT MODEL</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen30">SIMULATION PLATFORM</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen31">CONNECTING THE VERIFICATION TEST BENCH TO THE VIRTUAL ECU
2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen32">COMPARISON: TRADITIONAL TEST BENCH VS VIRTUAL TEST BENCH 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen33">Case Study One: Transmission Management System 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen34">Discrete Outputs</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen35">Discrete Inputs</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen36">BENEFITS TO DATE 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen37">FUTURE INVESTIGATION AND IMPROVEMENTS</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen38">CONCLUSIONS 2</a>
    </p>
    <p class="level_0">
      <a href="IDSBookout.html#NCXGen39">ACKNOWLEDGMENTS 2</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code of my form, i used the private variable "nexturl" because the webbrowser2 don't seem detect that the url has changed when i click on a link on the webbrowser3 (the link are the same, change only the bookmark).

```
private Uri nexturl = null;

private void Event_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    nexturl = e.Url;
    webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));//necessary, the webbrowser2 don't see that the url has changed
}

private void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser3.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(Event_Navigating);
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted);
}

void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (nexturl != null)
    {
        webBrowser2.Navigate(nexturl);
        nexturl = null;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser3.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser3.Navigate(new Uri("file://" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "IDSBooktoc.html"));
}
```

Comment: In my code, Event_Navigating method does not gets called.

Comment: I've tryed the code on my pc before post it. Can you provide a piece of html file?

Comment: If you debug the project, the event webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted is called?

Comment: i have added my HTML.

Comment: I hope u are getting what i want to do.. Here in this html i have some links which refers to another HTML file. I have placed this in webBrowser3 and if i click on any of the link in this HTML file, i want to open its content in webBrowser2. And bothe webBrowsers are placed on single form.

Comment: i am getting this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this line "webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById(e.Node.Name).ScrollIntoView(true);"

Comment: In what event do you have this piece of code? In my code the webbrowser2 is in the correct position after loaded

Comment: sorry, i have wriiten wrong.. Actually the prob that i am facing is even now, after clicking on links on webbrowser3, " This program cannot display the webpage" is displayed on webbrowser2. Still now, i am not getting its contents on its click..

Answer (score 1):

```
private string tocpage = "IDSBooktoc.html";
private string outpage = "IDSBookout.html";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load toc, only for parsing
    webBrowser2.Visible = false;
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser2.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(tocpage);
}

void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Populate treeview
    foreach (HtmlElement ele in webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(ele.GetAttribute("href"), ele.InnerText);
    }
    //detach event
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted);
    //change webbrowser2 source
    webBrowser2.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(outpage);
}

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string selected = e.Node.Name; //IDSBookout.html#NCXGen0
    string bookmark = selected.Substring(selected.IndexOf("#") + 1);
    webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById(bookmark).ScrollIntoView(true);
    webBrowser2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: i am facing some problem, my nodes comes twice in treeview. Example :- structure of my tree view is
-Introduction 1
-TRADITIONAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS
-Introduction 1
-TRADITIONAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS
But it should be like 
-Introduction 1
-TRADITIONAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT AND VERIFICATION PROCESS

Comment: when i deleted " webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted);" then my problem has been resolved. But i am not getting why we had written this line in code .. Can u please explain the use of this codeline ?

Comment: I wrote this line of code because i use the webbrowser2, in first instance, to parse the toc file. In my code i: 1)read html file 2) ondocumentcompleted event populate the treeview 3) detach event because i don't need it. Perhaps you parse your html in another event?

Comment: great thanks for your help. Actually, it was my mistake, i myself wasn't clearing nodes before firing this event.

Answer (score 0):

The difference by my code and you code is that you don't use the url for load the page but you set directly html in webbrowser2 and webbrowser3.

Try in this way:

```
private string tocpage = "IDSBooktoc.html";
private string outpage = "IDSBookout.html";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser3.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(tocpage);
    webBrowser2.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(outpage);

    webBrowser3.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser3_Navigating);
}

private void webBrowser3_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    //scroll webbrowser2
    string bookmark = e.Url.Fragment.Replace("#", "");
    webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById(bookmark).ScrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Comment: i have one more ques .. if instead of webbrowser3, i use treeview then also will it work ??

Comment: if i am using treeview then which event should i fire in order to navigate from treeview to webbrowser ?

Comment: Try the AfterSelect event

Comment: can u please write me the code to write for treeview ?